# How to specify random effects names in a newdata data.frame used in predict() function? - lme4

Tags: r, predict, lme4

I have a problem using the predict() function in lme4.
More precisely, I am not very clear on how to declare the names of random effects to be used in the newdata data frame, which I feed the predict() function with, in order to get some predictions.
I will try and describe my problem in detail.

**Data**

The data I am working with is longitudinal. I have 119 observations, for each of which I have several (6-7) measurements for each observation, which represent the size of proteins, which aggregate in time and grow bigger (let's call it LDL).

**Model**

The model used to describe this process is a Richard's curve (generalized logistic function), which can be written as

[image]

Now, I fit a separate curve for the group of measurements of each observation, with the following fixed, random effects, and variables:

**alpha_fix** - a fixed effect for alpha 
**alpha|Obs** - a random effect for alpha, which varies among observations
**gamma_fix** - a fixed effect for gamma 
**gamma|Obs** - a random effect for gamma, which varies among observations 
**delta_f** -  a fixed effect 
**Time** -  a continuous variable, time in hours 
**LDL** -  response variable, continuous, representing size of proteins at time point t.

**Predictions**

Once I fit the model, I want to use it to predict the value of  **LDL** at a specific time point, for each observation. In order to do this, I need to use the predict function and assign a data frame for **newdata**. reading through the documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/lme4.pdf), it says the following:

> If any random effects are included in re.form (see below), newdata
>   must contain columns corresponding to all of the grouping variables
>   and random effects used in the original model, even if not all are
>   used in prediction; however, they can be safely set to NA in this case

Now, the way I understand this, I need to have a data frame newdata, which in my case contains the following columns: "Time", "Obs", "alpha_f", "gamma_f", "delta_f", as well as two columns for the random effects of alpha and gamma, respectively. However, I am not sure how these two columns with random effects should be named, in order for the predict() function to understand them. I tried with "alpha|Obs" and "gamma|Obs", as well as "Obs$alpha", "Obs$gamma", but both throw the error

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :    random effects specified in re.form
>   that were not present in original model.

I was wondering whether anyone has any idea what the correct way to do this is.

For completeness, the code used to fit the model is provided below:

```
    ModelFunction = function (alpha, gamma, delta, Time) {

  15 + (alpha-15) / (1 + exp ((gamma-Time) / delta)) 
}


ModelGradient = deriv(body(ModelFunction) [[2]], namevec = c ("alpha", "gamma", "delta"), function.arg = ModelFunction)

starting_conditions = c (alpha = 5000, gamma = 1.5, delta = 0.2) # Based on visual observation

fit = nlmer (
  LDL ~ 
    ModelGradient (alpha, gamma, delta, Time) 
  ~ (gamma | Obs) + (alpha | Obs), 
  start = starting_conditions, 
  nlmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)),
  data = ldlData)
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could give me some advice.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please show the code used for fitting the model. Anyway, I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding. `newdata` needs to contain all *variables* referenced in the formula for model fitting. If your formula was something like `y ~ x + y + (x + y | g)`, you need `x`, `y` and `g` in the data.frame for prediction.

Comment: If you use `nlmer` and have a formula like `circumference ~ SSlogis(age, Asym, xmid, scal) ~ Asym|Tree`, you still need only the variables, i.e., `age` and `Tree`, and not the parameters in the data.frame for prediction.

Comment: Essentially, the original data.frame used for fitting the model contains all necessary variables and could be passed to `newdata`.

Comment: Hi, @Roland, thanks for your comment. I did of course try first using a newdata data frame with the exact same structure of the data frame I used to fit the model (3 columns. respectively - Obs, Time, LDL), but it threw an error
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'alpha' not found.

Comment: I think we need a reproducible example that replicates the error.

Comment: Hi, @Roland, sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately the data I am using is patients' data, hence I cannot share it.